# tkinter make verticle notebook tabs stay on top

Tags: python, tkinter

this is my code to create a window containing 5 tabs:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class VNotebook(ttk.Notebook):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        style = ttk.Style()
        style.configure("TNotebook",tabposition='ws', borderwidth=0)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("450x400+525+350")
root.after(1, lambda: root.focus_force())

tabs = VNotebook(root)
tabs.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

tab1 = tk.Frame(tabs)
tab2 = tk.Frame(tabs)
tab3 = tk.Frame(tabs)
tab4 = tk.Frame(tabs)
tab5 = tk.Frame(tabs)

tabs.add(tab1, text="tab1")
tabs.add(tab2, text="tab2")
tabs.add(tab3, text="tab3")
tabs.add(tab4, text="tab4")
tabs.add(tab5, text="tab5")

root.mainloop()
```

and this is the
[retult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmsSe.png)

but I want the tabs go to the
[red circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gle23.png)

please help me, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the `tabposition` set to `ws`, which means "West-South" (South being the *bottom* of the screen). Change it to `wn`, which is "West-North," because North is the *top* of the screen. This should solve your problem.

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class VNotebook(ttk.Notebook):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        style = ttk.Style()
        style.configure("TNotebook",tabposition='wn', borderwidth=0)
        # Tab position is West-North             ^^

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("450x400+525+350")
root.after(1, lambda: root.focus_force())

tabs = VNotebook(root)
tabs.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

tab1 = tk.Frame(tabs)
tab2 = tk.Frame(tabs)
tab3 = tk.Frame(tabs)
tab4 = tk.Frame(tabs)
tab5 = tk.Frame(tabs)

tabs.add(tab1, text="tab1")
tabs.add(tab2, text="tab2")
tabs.add(tab3, text="tab3")
tabs.add(tab4, text="tab4")
tabs.add(tab5, text="tab5")

root.mainloop()
```